# Sowing strategies for Harvest Moon

Tags: harvest-moon-gbc

Is there a good strategy, or layout, for optimizing watering and harvesting your crops in Harvest Moon GBC?

I used to seed in separate 3x3 squares, cutting out a tile in one of the sides, so I could water the whole thing in just two uses of the sprinkler.
But then I got the golden sickle and golden hoe and that makes it very difficult to create this pattern, given their properties.

Is there any way I can use the golden tools to my advantage, saving time and effort to care for my crops?

Comment: Which Harvest Moon are you asking about?  It depends greatly on the game.

Comment: @fbueckert Sorry about that, I've amended the question

Comment: I believe I got the right one for the tag; there are two HMs for GBC, but I don't think HM3 has golden tools.  At least, not that I could find.